# Why won't my 5 child divs go 100% across the parent div when they are set at 20%?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div that is set to 100% width and when I set each of its 5 children divs to 20% each, theoretically each child div should be contained inside the parent div, rather than breaking on a second line.

I have done this before and it has worked, but it isn't working now.

It looks somewhat like this -

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
    <div class="child5"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the code - http://jsfiddle.net/dtk5zL1e/

I also am using bootstrap if that makes any difference.

Comment: By default, `<div>` elements act as [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) and will "begin on new lines". You'll need to change their [display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) or [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a common class for the elements you want to float and then add:

```
          <div class="container">

                <h1 class="versions">Choose Versions for Report</h1>

                <div class="compare nav">
hello
                </div>

                <div class="first-draft nav">
hi
                </div>

                <div class="second-draft nav">
hello
                </div>

                <div class="third-draft nav">
hi
                </div>

                <div class="fourth-draft nav">
hello
                </div>

            </div>
```

and then **CSS**

```
   .nav{
    float:left;
    }
```

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/dtk5zL1e/1/

Answer (score 1):

By default, browsers always place a line break before and after the div element. However, this can be changed with CSS using

```
display: inline;
```

In your case, using the width property, you should use

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Note: using `display:inline-block`, you'll need to [remove the white space](http://jsfiddle.net/cmeth70s/) between elements or else the spaces will be [represented on the page](http://jsfiddle.net/cmeth70s/1/).